# Add description block in addition to title to magnific popup WYSIWYG v14

Tags: jquery, css

I have implemented the magnific popup for a photo gallery consisting of 35 images using WYSIWYG Web Builder v14 extension.  I've managed a few CSS changes to style the pop-up but can't figure out how to add a block for a description, underneath the (title) and (image # of images).

I am NOT a coder and hope for some sort of example to allow me to make this work.
This is the code that is presented to work with:

```
<div id="PhotoGallery1">
   <div class="thumbnails">
      <div class="thumbnail">
         <a href="images/1953.jpg" data-rel="" title="1953"><img alt="1953" src="images/tn_1953.jpg"><div class="caption">1953<div class="description">this is a test of the description<br>2nd line of description</div>
</div></a>
```

The result is the image (which works great) with 1953 (the title) at the lower left of the image (which is fine) and the identifier (1 of XX) at the lower right of the image. (this is also good).

Now I want to add a block that will allow me to pull the "div class = description" as shown above and have it directly below the title and identifier.  For example a white block the width of the image with black letters and a font size that matches the title font size.

I believe I'll need to add some sort of script and css but have not clue as to what to add.

The end result I hope will look something like this:
[image: desired result]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Comment: Thanks for both the fix and the link to editing help, I need as much as I can get.